# Type Error: .join is not a function sockets .io in node client server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sockets, socket.io

I want to create a room for a chat app I'm building in node and vue js. Unfortunately I keep getting error .join is not a function for socket .io. I understand its a server sided function so I am using it in server side only yet the problem still persists. All the other functions like .emit() works fine.

Here's my Index.js

```
let io = require('./socket')
let server = app.listen(8000)
io = io.init(server)
io.on('connection', socket => {
  console.log('Client Connected')
})
```

Ive taken this piece of code from Udemy's Maxmilian's Node js master course.

Here's my socket.js where I export the socket functions. Essentially I have created a sharing instance to work with socket in other files.

socket.js

```
let io

module.exports = {
    init: httpServer => {
        io = require('socket.io')(httpServer,  {
            cors: {
              origin: '*',
              methods: ['GET', 'POST'],
            }
          })
        return io
    },
    getIO: () => {
        if(!io){
            console.log('Socket is not Initialized')
        }
        return io
    } 
}
```

Last but not least heres my customer_controller.js where I try to join the socket.join()
customer_controller.js

```
exports.getMessages = async(req, res, next) => {
  try {
    let messages = await Message.find({
      users: [ req.user.email, 'admin@demo.com' ] })
      .populate('sender')
      .sort({"updatedAt": 1})
    io.getIO().join(req.user.email)
    res.json(messages)
  } catch(err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
}
```

Here's my detailed error!

```
TypeError: io.getIO(...).join is not a function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anybody wanted to know the solution. It should be:

```
io.getIO(socket => {
      socket.join(req.user.email)
    })
```

and not

```
io.getIO().join(req.user.email)
```

since socket has the function called .join() not io. Here's the docs. See carefully Ive missed several times. Although I'm still facing a problem regarding console logging socket.rooms

When I do

```
console.log(socket.rooms)
```

in customer_controller.js, it returns nothing not even an error. But when I do it in index.js file like so:

index.js

```
io.on('connection', socket => {
   console.log(socket.rooms)
})
```

It returns a set. If anyone has more efficient way to deal with this please post your answer. Ill accept it as solution. Thank you